# username password not prompted second time

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-security, basic-authentication

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS.  I have enabled basic authentication for the service. 
Username/password is asked the first time when the service is hosted through iis and not for the subsequent requests.  How do I prompt for login each time the service is requested?  The web.config for the security settings are

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
</security>
```

I have SSL enabled on the service by creating a self-signed certificate.

Comment: does the browser cache the username pwd and set it appropritely whenever the service is requested successive times?

Comment: if it caches where does it cache and how do i stop if from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the service from the browser you cannot turn this behavior off. When the service is accessed for the first time you are prompted for credentials which are then internally cached until you clear history or close the browser (or perhaps also browser tab). The browser uses credentials for all subsequent requests - basic authentication is always handled per every request.

That is because browser is in the first place used to browse web content and without this feature you if you would like to access secured page you will have to access credentials for every single html, css, js or picture file secured on the site with basic authentication.

Comment: thnks ladislav.i was thinking something like the service is hosted in iis and basic authentication was enabled in iss.so once the request hits iis and gets itself authenticated, it does not require for further authentications. anyways doubt cleared.thnkx.